# calling a function from a another function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call function add from function count_change,but i get an error that add is not a function..what am i doing wrong ?

```
var stat = missing_stat();
function missing_stat(){
    template ="noun verb apples .that is why he is so adj .  also noun verb apples but he is so adj . noun verb oranges ";
    var fields =template.split(' ');
    for (i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
    {
        if(fields[i]=='noun'){
            fields[i]= noun_change();
        }
        var add = (function () {
            var counter = 0;
            return function () {return counter += 1;}
        })();

        function count_change(){
            var count_noun= add();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You using extra bracket in `var add = (function() {...` just remove them and please use right tabulation for next time its hard to define errors in your coding style

```
var stat = missing_stat();
function missing_stat(){
    template ="noun verb apples .that is why he is so adj .  also noun verb apples but he is so adj . noun verb oranges ";
    var fields =template.split(' ');
    for (i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
    {
        if(fields[i]=='noun'){
            fields[i]= noun_change();


        }
        var add = function () {
                var counter = 0;
                return counter += 1;
        };

        function count_change(){
            var count_noun= add();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Part of the indentation is my fault. But you should have seen how it was before.

Comment: Uhm... on closer inspection I was wrong with my (now removed) comment to the question, Those parentheses made sense, because the function assigned to `add` returns a function itself.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'll assume that inside that `if` you wanted to call `count_change`, not `noun_change`.

When you call `count_change`, `add` has not been defined yet. Search "closures".

You can avoid this by moving the definition of `add` before the call to `count_change`, like this

```
var stat = missing_stat();
function missing_stat(){
    template ="noun verb apples .that is why he is so adj .  also noun verb apples but he is so adj . noun verb oranges ";
    var fields =template.split(' ');
    for (i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
    {
        var add = (function () {
            var counter = 0;
            return function () {return counter += 1;}
        })();

        if(fields[i]=='noun'){
            fields[i]= noun_change();
        }


        function count_change(){
            var count_noun= add();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, `counter` is going to be reset everytime you call `add`, so I'm not really sure what you were trying to do here.